# Unable to store results of a loop

Tags: r, function, loops, storage

I have a data.frame of which I try to test (with WilcoxRankSum-Test) 1st and 2nd row, then 3rd and 4th row and so on.  Therefore I wrote a loop.  Because I have to apply this to multiple data frames, I created a function to store this loop and apply it to others later.
I tried to reset the brackets `{}` several times or to replace `pval[i]` with sapply as recommended in several other threads.

In my opinion the loops works fine. But the loop cannot access `pval`. Sorry to bother you with a common problem.  I am a newly self-taught (all from threads ;) ). But I cannot find the problem.  If you see shortcuts to make life easier,
I really would be glad about any comments.

Here is my code:

```
ZP <- function(data){  
library(exactRankTests)
pval  <- vector(length=nrow(data))
k  <- seq(1,nrow(data)-1, by=2)
for (i in seq_along(k)) {
pval[i] <-  wilcox.exact(as.numeric(data[k[i],6:10]),
                           as.numeric(data[k[i]+1,6:10]), 
                           alternative = "greater", conf.level=0.95)$p.value 
return(pval)
}
}
```

Here is the result:

```
ZP(realdata)
 [1] 0.8492063 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [9] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[17] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
[25] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

I want it to look like this, so I can cbind it to the data later:

```
ZP(realdata)
 [1] "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval"
[12] "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"   
[23] "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"    "pval" "0"
```

My data looks like:

```
      Proband Lauf Interleukin Ansatz  Zeitpunkt Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5
 1       1    1        IFNy   stim     ZP0         7     2     3     3     7
 2       1    1        IFNy    neg     ZP0         3     2     0     2     1
```

Comment: Your function does not seem to be returning anything: you probably want its last line to be `pval` or `return(pval)`.

Comment: Also, your curly brackets are out of place because you're storing into `pval[[i]]` outside of your `for`-loop.

Comment: I want the results to be returned in a vector of length=nrow(data), so I can cbind it later to the data.

Comment: Move `return(pval)` outside of your for-loop). Your for-loop should be a sequence (e.g., `1:length(k)`), presently it is just one number (`length(k)`).

Comment: Changed it already, but does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got my loop to work.  Once I ran the function and applied it to a set of data,
it will return my values. But when R shows me pval, which I set to '0' before, its still 0.  I cannot seem to access pval outside of the function.  Its probably something basic I am missing.

```
P <- function(x){  
  library(exactRankTests)
  pval  <- vector(length=nrow(x))
  k  <- seq(1, nrow(x), by=2)
  for (i in seq_along(k)) {
  pval[k[i]] <-  wilcox.exact(as.numeric(x[k[i],6:10]),
                              as.numeric(x[k[i]+1,6:10]), 
                              alternative = "greater", conf.level=0.95)$p.value} 
   return(pval)
}
```

Comment: When a function returns something, you need to assign it if you want to use it. If you want it to be called `pval`, assign it that way! `pval <- P(yourdata)`. It doesn't matter what you call it inside the function, it matters to what name you assign it when you call the function.

Comment: Hi thanks, i knew it was something basic.  But how can I then automize the storing into pval?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand your problem. To automate things, put them in an R script and `source()` the script to run all the commands in it, which can include an assignment like in my comment above. In general, having a function which modifies or creates new variables by itself is the paradigm in object-oriented programming. In this area, R is a functional programming language, where running a function shouldn't have "side-effects", i.e., it shouldn't just create a new variable in your work space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy with a little less code:

```
library(exactRankTests)
# sample data
realdata <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),nrow=40))

# odd row indices
x <- seq(1,nrow(realdata)-1,by=2)

pvals <- vector(length=length(x)) # empty vector
for(i in seq_along(x))
    pvals[i] <- wilcox.exact(as.numeric(realdata[x[i],]),
                             as.numeric(realdata[x[i]+1,]),
                             alternative="greater",
                             conf.level=0.95)$p.value
```

Comment: What do you mean by nrow(odd)? Did you mean nrow(x). This returns me NULL.

Comment: I changed it accordingly, still does not work.  Will update the changed code above. Thx

Comment: @newbymedicalstats You should probably provide a sample of your data, for example using `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this attempt (which might potentially work canonically with `wilcox.exact()`)?

```
# data <- iris[rep(1:50,each=2)+c(0,50),] # use some flowers for demonstration
p.vals <- as.numeric(by(data[,1:4],rep(seq(50),each=2), function(rowpair) 
    wilcox.test(rowpair[,1], rowpair[,2], alt="greater")$p.val))
```

Btw: In case you are only interested in `p.val`, specifying `conf.level=0.95` seems dispensable.

Comment: Did you mean `funtion(colpair)'?

Comment: @newbymedicalstats: Instead of combining explicit iteration with a `{}` block of commands, the idea is to invoke some function that takes care of using the elements of some data structure as parameters for some function (and `by()` simultaneously takes another variable to define subgroups, see `?by`).